# Search by Image with SQL Server database and VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am tired to make the search engine to run. Just I want to make search by image in my SQL Server database by making a choice of the column with same image.

I tried to make it with this code:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from TBL_Image Where Image = " & Image, sqlcon)
```

Can anyone help me?

[Picture of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGLzI.png)

This is my code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Image

Public Class Form1
   Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("server=.\MOHAMED; database=DB_Image; 
   integrated security = true")

Dim cmd As SqlCommand

Sub selectImage(ByVal Image As Image)

    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from TBL_Image Where Image = " & Image, sqlcon)

    sqlcon.Open()

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    dr.Read()

    txtShow.Text = dr(0)

    Dim sora2() As Byte = CType(dr(1), Byte())

    Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream(sora2)

    pbox3.Image = Image.FromStream(ms2)

    dr.Read()

    Dim sora3() As Byte = CType(dr(1), Byte())

    Dim ms3 As New MemoryStream(sora3)

    pbox4.Image = Image.FromStream(ms3)

    dr.Read()

    Dim sora4() As Byte = CType(dr(1), Byte())

    Dim ms4 As New MemoryStream(sora4)

    pbox5.Image = Image.FromStream(ms4)

    dr.Read()

    Dim sora5() As Byte = CType(dr(1), Byte())

    Dim ms5 As New MemoryStream(sora5)

    pbox6.Image = Image.FromStream(ms5)

    dr.Read()

    Dim sora6() As Byte = CType(dr(1), Byte())

    Dim ms6 As New MemoryStream(sora6)

    pbox7.Image = Image.FromStream(ms6)

    dr.Read()

    Dim sora7() As Byte = CType(dr(1), Byte())

    Dim ms7 As New MemoryStream(sora7)

    pbox8.Image = Image.FromStream(ms7)

    sqlcon.Close()

    dr.Close()

End Sub


Private Sub btnBrowse1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse1.Click
    ofd1.Filter = "All Images |*.PNG; *.JPG; *.BMP; *.GIF; *.JPEG"

    If ofd1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        pbox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd1.FileName)
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click

    cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into TBL_Image(Description, Image) values(@Description, @Image)", sqlcon)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.Text)).Value = txtDescription.Text

    Dim ms1 As New MemoryStream
    pbox1.Image.Save(ms1, pbox1.Image.RawFormat)

    Dim Image() As Byte = ms1.ToArray

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = Image

    sqlcon.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    sqlcon.Close()

    MsgBox("Added successfully")


End Sub

Private Sub btnBrowse2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse2.Click
    ofd2.Filter = "All Images |*.PNG; *.JPG; *.BMP; *.GIF; *.JPEG"

    If ofd2.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        pbox2.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd2.FileName)
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim msnew As New MemoryStream
    pbox2.Image.Save(msnew, pbox2.Image.RawFormat)

    Dim Image() As Byte = msnew.ToArray


    selectImage(pbox2.Image)


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Given that your generating a `String` containing SQL code, what exactly do you expect it to look like that it will contain text that will somehow be matched to some data in your database? Have you done any reading on how an image would be matched using SQL?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)